# UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout insets does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have implemented `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in my ViewController, and specify insets using the following code:

> ```
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
>                                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
>                                       insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
>     return sectionInsets
> }
> ```

But this function is never executed when I use breakpoints to debug.
As I have already specified the delegate of the UICollectionView to the ViewController, I do not know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set layouts for a collection view, do the following inside the collectionViewClass:

**1. implement the method `getLayout`:**

```
func getLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout
    {
        let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout =  UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 25, left: 25, bottom: 25, right: 25)

        return layout as UICollectionViewLayout

    }
```

**2. set property from method in `ViewDidLoad`:**

```
self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = self.getLayout()
```